# Identify current wordpress theme

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes

I want a theme very similar to these two websites. I am a newbie to wordpress and am trying to understand what theme is it. It looks like both the sites have a similar theme. Is there a way I can fin out what is the theme that they are using? Any help would be appreciated.

http://www.evanmarckatz.com/
http://www.winggirlmethod.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your browser

- select "View page source"
- search for `style.css`
- you'll find something like this: `http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/ThemeName/style.css`
- there you already have the theme name, and if you open the URL you also gonna see at the beginning of the stylesheet a header with all the information about the theme and its author

Comment: It might also be helpful to load the `style.css` file directly in the browser. If the Theme is publicly released, the header docs in `style.css` likely will have some additional, useful information.

Comment: Oh wait; you said that in your answer. Sorry, I somehow misread that. :)

Comment: You explained it better, Chip ;)